# Populating the HTML drop-down list with a value that is in the MySQL databse and making it 'selected' while there are other options in the list

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, drop-down-menu

Let's say I have an HTML dropdown menu as,

```
<p>General Medical History: 
<select name="otherproblem">
    <option value="Nothing">Nothing</option>
    <option value="Allergy: Penicillin">Allergy: Penicillin</option>
    <option value="Aspirin">Aspirin</option>
    <option value="Erythromycin">Erythromycin</option>
    <option value="Latex or Rubber Products">Latex or Rubber Products</option>
    <option value="Codeine">Codeine</option>
    <option value="Tetracycline">Tetracycline</option>
    <option value="Germicides/Pesticides, Foods">Germicides/Pesticides, Foods</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
    <option value="Asthma">Asthma</option>
    <option value="Bleeding Disorders">Bleeding Disorders</option>
    <option value="Diabetes">Diabetes</option>
    <option value="Epilepsy">Epilepsy</option>
    <option value="GI disorders">GI disorders</option>
    <option value="Heart disease">Heart disease</option>
    <option value="Hepatitis">Hepatitis</option>
    <option value="Jaundice">Jaundice</option>
    <option value="Liver disease">Liver disease</option>
    <option value="Neoplasm">Neoplasm</option>
    <option value="Psychiatric Problems">Psychiatric Problems</option>
    <option value="Respiratory diseases">Respiratory diseases</option>
    <option value="Rheumatic fever">Rheumatic fever</option>
</select>
</p>
```

By selecting one of the options, I am adding the particular value to the database as a VARCHAR.

Now I am calling them back, let's say, for an edit, so I need the entered data back to the same form, where I could retrieve all the other things to text boxes. But I have no idea how to get the value from the db and make it selected in this dropdown list. All I could do is saving the retrieved value  from db to a variable named,   `$otherproblem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, one is to load the list along the lines of:

```
<?
    $otherproblem = "Erythromycin";
?>
<p>General Medical History: 
<select name="otherproblem">
<?
$result = mysql_query("query to get the list of options");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if(strcmp($row['Problem'],$otherproblem)===0){ $selected = 'selected="selected"'; } else { $selected = ""; }
?>
<option <?=$other?> value="<?=$row['Problem'];?>"><?=$row['Problem'];?></option>
<? } ?>
```

Dirty, but it will work with the way you have it setup currently. You can also rig it by simply making the item select at the top of the list, and then the full list like this:

```
<?
    $otherproblem = "Erythromycin";
?>
<p>General Medical History: 
<select name="otherproblem">
<option selected="selected" value="<?=$otherproblem;?>"><?=$otherproblem;?></option>
<?
$result = mysql_query("query to get the list of options");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<option value="<?=$row['Problem'];?>"><?=$row['Problem'];?></option>
<? } ?>
```

There is much neater ways to do this, but without seeing how you are pulling the data, these two options will work in any case.

Comment: I am running a query in the file as, $recall = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM history WHERE id='$id'") or die(mysql_error()); $getdetails = mysql_fetch_array($recall); $otherproblem = $getdetails['otherproblem']; 
I am having a parse error when I tried @tmpmember's method. That looked like an easy method for me.

Comment: if you cycle through the query ie: $result = mysql_query("query"); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ $otherproblem=$row['otherproblem']; } it should work fine. I am running this code now as a test and seems to be fine as long as the query holds a result.

Comment: <option <?php if($otherproblem=="Nothing"){ echo 'selected="selected"';}?> value="Nothing"> Nothing</option>
Is this coding wrong? If I do like that, I am getting a parse error...

Comment: that code in theory should work. What is the error you get? try <? if(strcmp($otherproblem,"Nothing")){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>

Comment: sorry <? if(strcmp($otherproblem,"Nothing")===0){ echo 'selected="selected"'; }?>

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\cleft\test.php on line 73

Comment: This is the line where I input my first code if this 'selected'. But i there is no mistake I could figure out :(

Comment: <option <?php if(strcmp($otherproblem,"Nothing")){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> value="Nothing"> Nothing</option> 
This is how I entered

Comment: change that to: <?php if(strcmp($otherproblem,"Nothing")===0){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?> value="Nothing"> Nothing</option>

Comment: The thing is I am using Sublime Text to code. I see the first 'selected' in 'selected="selected"' is in blue. Any ideas? Normally all the echos will be in yellow.

Comment: sublime may have a hard time understanding nested quotations. Aptana does that on occasion.

Comment: there must be if you are getting a parse error. can you pastebin your entire code?

Comment: Check it http://pastebin.com/Z9WzpSa5 
I have error coming in Line 73 where I am comparing the sex, in this case.

Comment: I see you're issue, you are echoing you're HTML.  change line 73 to: <option value="Male"'; if($sex="Male"){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } echo '>Male</option> and line 74 to: <option value="Female"'; if($sex="Female"){ echo 'selected="selected"'; } echo '>Female</option>

Comment: Just get to know it is not working. :( But if I echo $sex it shows the correct value. But the dropdown menu isn't showing the correct value.

Comment: you missed the spaces, change line 79 too: if($sex="Male"){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } and line 83 to: if($sex="Female"){ echo ' selected="selected"'; } echo '>Female</option></select></p>'; there was no space for "selected" and thus was not a valid option parameter.

Comment: Still the same. Sex stays on "Female" in form. And Other problem stays on "Rheumatic fever"

Comment: pastebin your outputed HTML or link me to the page with the output HTML please

Comment: I have attached the output file's screenshot since I haven't hosted it yet, http://i.imgur.com/FL1bg.png?1 and this is the db data http://i.imgur.com/rbD6T.png?1

Comment: i need to see the output html as source please.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/KjyFEg8J Here is is the source code of the html file which has the form. I just noticed, every option is echoed the 'selected'. How come? :-/

Comment: Gosh, Just realized my mistake. I have compared the option value using single '=', it should be '==' right? :-/ Now it is working. Thanks a lot for your time again.

Comment: if you are checking a string against another string, use === instead of ==

Comment: OK. But what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You would modify each option tag to look like this:

```
<option value="Nothing" <?=$otherproblem === 'Nothing' ? 'selected="selected"' : ''?>>Nothing</option>
```

Each one should compare the value from the database to the value of the option tag and add the selected attribute if they are equal.

Comment: If you don't have short tags enabled then you would need to change `<?=` to `<?php echo`

Comment: Yeah, and I had a different error. I was echoing the htlm form wrong. Got it now. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Often, you will be loading the list of options from the database as well.  You'll loop through the list and construct the `<option>` tags on the fly.  As you do that, you compare the option value being created with the value retrieved from the earlier submission, and, if they match, you add the "selected" attribute to the option tag.

Comment: Thanks to you and @J.Money for your help. I will look into them. Sorry I couldn't up-vote your answers. I haven't got enough reputation points yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this:

```
<?php

$otherproblem = "Aspirin";

$dropdown = array(
    "Nothing",
    "Allergy: Penicillin",
    "Aspirin",
    "Erythromycin",
    "Latex or Rubber Products",
    "Codeine",
    "Tetracycline",
    "Germicides/Pesticides, Foods",
    "Other",
    "Asthma",
    "Bleeding Disorders",
    "Diabetes",
    "Epilepsy",
    "GI disorders",
    "Heart disease",
    "Hepatitis",
    "Jaundice",
    "Liver disease",
    "Neoplasm",
    "Psychiatric Problems",
    "Respiratory diseases",
    "Rheumatic fever"
);

?>
<p>General Medical History: 
<select name="otherproblem">
    <?php foreach ($dropdown as $name): ?>
        <option <?php if ($otherproblem == $name) print('selected="selected"');?> value="<?php print($name);?>"><?php print($name);?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</p>
```

**Way 2:**

```
<?php
    $otherproblem = "Erythromycin";
?>
<p>General Medical History: 
<select name="otherproblem">
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Nothing"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Nothing">Nothing</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Allergy: Penicillin"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Allergy: Penicillin">Allergy: Penicillin</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Aspirin"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Aspirin">Aspirin</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Erythromycin"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Erythromycin">Erythromycin</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Latex or Rubber Products"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Latex or Rubber Products">Latex or Rubber Products</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Codeine"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Codeine">Codeine</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Tetracycline"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Tetracycline">Tetracycline</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Germicides/Pesticides, Foods"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Germicides/Pesticides, Foods">Germicides/Pesticides, Foods</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Other"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Other">Other</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Asthma"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Asthma">Asthma</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Bleeding Disorders"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Bleeding Disorders">Bleeding Disorders</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Diabetes"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Diabetes">Diabetes</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Epilepsy"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Epilepsy">Epilepsy</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "GI disorders"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="GI disorders">GI disorders</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Heart disease"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Heart disease">Heart disease</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Hepatitis"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Hepatitis">Hepatitis</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Jaundice"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Jaundice">Jaundice</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Liver disease"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Liver disease">Liver disease</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Neoplasm"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Neoplasm">Neoplasm</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Psychiatric Problems"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Psychiatric Problems">Psychiatric Problems</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Respiratory diseases"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Respiratory diseases">Respiratory diseases</option>
    <option <?php if($otherproblem == "Rheumatic fever"){print('selected="selected"');}?> value="Rheumatic fever">Rheumatic fever</option>
</select>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks tmpmember. But I am getting a parse error. Have no idea :(